Creating a loop of means
I am using rnorm as a data set and I am trying to make a loop that will take 100 random samples using n=25, mean = 10 and SD=10. I then want to get the mean of each sample and turn it into a histogram of the sample means.
Using various sites I've put together this:
normloop25 <- data.frame(ID = 1:100, Value = rnorm(100, 10, 10))
sample_size <- 25
random_sample <-
  normloop25[sample(nrow(normloop25), sample_size), ]
n_repeats <- 100
samples_list_25 <- vector("list", n_repeats)

for (i in 1:100) {
  samples_list_25[[i]] <-
    normloop25[sample(nrow(normloop25), sample_size), ]
}
means <- sapply(samples_list_25, function(sample)
  mean(sample$Value))
combined_samplesA <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:n_repeats, function(i) {
  data.frame(Sample = i, Value = samples_list_25[[i]]$Value)
}))
hist(combined_samplesA, las = 1, col = 'blue')

It works until the end when I get
Error in hist.default(combined_samplesA, las = 1, col = "blue") :
'x' must be numeric

If you look at class(combined_samplesA), I think you'll find it's a data frame or a matrix, but hist() expects a numeric vector. You need to pull out a single column to give to hist().

That said, I think you're overcomplicating this a lot, I'll post a simplified answer...

If the only thing you want to analyze is the sample means, then you don't need to save each whole sample:
sample_means = sapply(1:100, \(x) mean(rnorm(25, mean = 10, sd = 10)))
hist(sample_means)


If you do want to save each draw, you can still simplify a lot:
n_repeats = 100
sample_n = 25
sample_mean = 10
sample_sd = 10

samples = replicate(
  n = n_repeats,
  expr = rnorm(
    n = sample_n,
    mean = sample_mean,
    sd = sample_sd
  )
)

## samples is a 25x100 matrix,
## each column is a replicate of 25 draws from the distribution
dim(samples)
# [1]  25 100

## make a histogram of the means of each column:
hist(colMeans(samples)) ## similar output as above


I used
sample_means = sapply(1:100, (x) mean(rnorm(25, mean = 10, sd = 10)))
hist(sample_means)
and it worked. Could you please explain what the (x) does? I understand that the sapply is specifying how many runs and the other is information about sample size, sd etc.

@Redd11 \(x) ... is an anonymous function that takes an argument x. It is equivalent to creating a function and using that function in sapply. It is equivalent to fn <- function() mean(rnorm(25, mean = 10, sd = 10)) and sapply(1:100, fn). See Advanced R functional programming for further info

The replicate or sapply loop isn't necessary. This will give exactly the same result: colMeans(matrix(rnorm(25 * 100, 10, 10), nrow = 25))

A ggplot2 / tidyverse variation with some formatting.
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(run = rep(1:100, each = 25),
           value = rnorm(100*25, 10, 10)) |>
  summarize(mean = mean(value), .by = run) |>
  ggplot(aes(mean)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, boundary = 0, closed = "left",
                 color = "black", fill = "gray90") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(1), minor_breaks = NULL) +
  theme_minimal()


or using ggthemes::theme_base()


There is ggthemes::theme_base() :)

A variation
M = colMeans(replicate(100, rnorm(25, mean = 10, sd = 10)))
hist(M, xlab = "sample means")

giving

